Aws CloudWatch metrics for each ECS java container
I have an ECS cluster running the same application on multiple fargate instances. I need to expose the micrometer metrics to cloudwatch and have a container identifier. For example, the metric jdbc.connections.active.value should be present for each container.
I used aws sdk 2 and succeeded to push the metrics to cloud watch with the following config but all the containers spill the values to the same CloudWatch metric.
import io.micrometer.cloudwatch2.CloudWatchConfig;
import io.micrometer.cloudwatch2.CloudWatchMeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Clock;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatch.CloudWatchAsyncClient;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {

    private String metricsNamespace = "test";

    @Bean
    public CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient() {
        return CloudWatchAsyncClient
                .builder()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistry getMeterRegistry() {
        CloudWatchConfig cloudWatchConfig = setupCloudWatchConfig();

        return new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(
                cloudWatchConfig,
                Clock.SYSTEM,
                cloudWatchAsyncClient());
    }

    private CloudWatchConfig setupCloudWatchConfig() {
        return new CloudWatchConfig() {

            private final Map<String, String> configuration = Map.of(
                    "cloudwatch.namespace", metricsNamespace,
                    "cloudwatch.step", Duration.ofSeconds(30).toString()
            );

            @Override
            public String get(@NotNull String key) {
                return configuration.get(key);
            }
        };
    }
}

I tried to add a dimension but with no luck:
private final Map<String, String> configuration = Map.of(
    "cloudwatch.namespace", metricsNamespace,
    "cloudwatch.step", Duration.ofSeconds(30).toString(),
    "cloudwatch.container_label", "container_name"
);

In CloudWatch, even if I have 2 containers up, there is still only one entry for my metrics:

(service-name is the namespace)
My expectation is to have one metric entry for each container for jdbc.connections.active.value

You might want to take a look at MeterFilter, and its commonTags method, you can attach instance data using it: https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/meter-filters.html#_transforming_metrics
Please be careful to not introduce high cardinality data: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/
